# AEM 6.2 password changing issue

Tags: adobe, aem

What is the procedure to change the admin passwords on aem6.2 publish instance?
When I change the admin password I got this error when accessing the system/console:
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /system/console/. Reason:
org.apache.sling.api.auth.NoAuthenticationHandlerException
Is there a documented procedure for changing the admin password on publish instance?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you always get that on publish instances. There is kind of a workaround. Before going to `/system/console` visit `/crx/de`, log in there and then go back to `/system/console`. This way you get a valid session (in CRX) that will authenticate you for the system console as well.

Comment: Hi Jens, Its not that simple. However i see your point. Ok , try to reproduce this and tell me if we can do something about it. Start up a new publisher instance with the runmode publish,nosamplecontent. Change Admin password via Touch UI. Dont change it in System/console/configMgr. Refresh the page. And while on the same browser , logout and login to crx/de , hit the /system/console page. You will see that error. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: hi, anyone find anything ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue